# DXA 1.2 Modules for Java?

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.2, 2013-sp1-hr1

I am using DXA 1.2 with Java for my applications, referring SDL docs here: [DXA Modules](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v2/GUID-5111ECC2-EC1C-4240-9AA8-F656CE5D6E5E), which says that there are four modules provided by DXA -

- Search
- Smart Target
- Google Analytics
- Media Manager

While saying these modules are available in DXA, does that defaults to .Net modules only?

Can find only Google Analytics module for java(also search module *unimplemented*) all other setups are for .Net, **any pointers** for finding other java modules?

Basically right now i was looking for Smart Target implementation so wanted to check if there are any sample/beta modules available/future plans before i start my custom implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from version 1.2, the SDL Digital Experience Accelerator (DXA) provides support for Java, which unfortunately because of time contrainst did not come with Java modules yet (so indeed the modules are currently only available for DXA .NET).

https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/tree/master/webapp-java simply contains placeholders for the modules which will be delivered as part of DXA 1.3 which we hope to release end of January, or early February, depending on the availability of SDL Web 8 GA (including all addons like SmartTarget).

I was expecting this would have been made clear in our documentation, but I see we have missed this. I'll see if I can fix that by making a clear statement that for DXA 1.2 there are no official Java modules available yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can check at following location: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/tree/master/webapp-java

i haven't used any of these. but for your reference.

Comment: Thanks @Raj , This project came with the dxa 1.2 java setup , have explored this already!

Comment: so there are multiple modules for 1.2 mentioned on the page. aren't these working?

Comment: Yes, some of them are not ex- Search.